# About splits in Java

Tags: java, split

I'm a Java beginner, so please bear with me if this is an extremely easy answer. 
Say I have code that looks like this:

```
String str;
    String [] splits;
    str = "The words never line up in such a way ";
    splits = str.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++)
        System.out.println(splits[i]);
```

What does Java do at the end of the string? After "way" there is a space; since there is no value after the space does Java decide not to split again?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you try it? The last element of `splits` should be an empty string.

Comment: Try it yourself? :) and tell us what happened?

Comment: @RobinKrahl No it wouldn't. `split` by default ignores any trailing empty strings.

Comment: @RohitJain oh, you are right. I mistaked it with two consecutive spaces.

Comment: The two ways to figure this out should be: 1) Like someone already said, compile the code and try it! (printing splits.length as well would be a good idea) 2) Google "java string split" (first hit will be the offical javadoc api documentation stating that "Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array" and also giving some examples of how splitting works)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Java documentation for split(), [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)](http://java.util.String#split%28String%20regex%29),

The split(String r) is equivalent to the split(String r, 0) method, which will ignore and not include any blank trailing empty strings. Specifically from the docs:

> "Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting
>   array."

So the last element in the array after the split will be "way"

You can confirm this by executing the code you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get any trailing space after delimiter if you use split method. Example

```
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        String str;
        String [] splits;
        str = "The words never line up in such a way     "; // some empty string after delimiter at end
        splits = str.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++)
            System.out.println(splits[i]);

        System.out.println("END");  
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
The
words
never
line
up
in
such
a
way
END
```

see no splitted string for end delimiters.

Now

```
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        String str;
        String [] splits;
        str = "The words never line up in such a way  yeah";
        splits = str.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++)
            System.out.println(splits[i]);

        System.out.println("END");  
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
The
words
never
line
up
in
such
a
way

yeah
END
```

see an extra string after delimiter which is also a empty string but not the trailing, so it will be in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve been looking at javadoc and here what it says about [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included** in the resulting array.

It seems that this method calls .split with two arguments:

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and **trailing empty strings will be discarded**.

thanks